# jquery droppable accept condition

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

How can i put a second accept condition for a droppable element in jquery ?

```
accept: ":not(.ui-sortable-helper)",
accept: function() {
if($("#playlist li").length <=<?php echo $max_item; ?>) return    true;              
},
```

This don't work

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Using a function is more flexible than using a selector - since it allows to do the same. I would put the whole condition in the function, as follows:

```
accept: function(element) {
   return (your_condition_1 
     && !(element.hasClass('ui-sortable-helper'))
   );
},
```